# Can't create folder on device using mac Android File Transfer app

Tags: storage, file-transfer, macos, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

When trying to create folder on Samsung Galaxy TAB 2 using the **Android File Transfer** app from my mac computer, I get an error alert:

> Could not connect to device. Try reconnecting or restarting your device".

What could be the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms. Neither reconnecting nor restarting my device helped. It turns out that there was already a folder with the same name as the one I was trying to create, and I just hadn't noticed it. So, Android File Transfer was giving me an incorrect error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and a reboot did the trick for me.